# Meteor version is different in local folder from global version

Tags: meteor

I git clone a package from github and checked the version inside that folder:

```
>meteor --version 
Extracting meteor-tool@1.4.2_7...     (forever running)
```

Then I go outside of that folder:

```
>meteor --version
Meteor 1.4.3.1
```

How can I run the global version inside a meteor project folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because that meteor project you checked out from github is targeting 1.4.2_7. Everytime you create a new meteor project, it saves the version that you used to create it (in a file inside the `.meteor` folder) so that if the api changes in new future versions, your project will still run (since it targets a specific version in time).

Because of this, when you go to run the project later, it will always use the targeted version (the version used to create the project.). If that version is not on your system, then it will download and install it first before running the app.  This is what you have observed.  It is downloading that certain version and it can take a very long time to do this depending in your connection speed (it often takes 15 - 25 minutes to do this on my machine at home.

One note, the project's meteor version can be changed by calling meteor update